# Fetch all documents from elastic search index kotlin reactive

Tags: kotlin, elasticsearch, reactive

I have tried to fetch all documents and got only the default number, I think 10K.
How can I fetch all 1M documents using elasticsearch version 7.15.2

```
class ESReactiveClientWrapper(

    val clientReader: ReactiveElasticsearchClient
) {

fun fetch(indexName: String): Flux<ESDocument> {
    val searchSourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder()
        .size(100)
        .sort("_id", SortOrder.ASC)

    return searchRecursive(indexName, searchSourceBuilder)
 }

 protected fun searchRecursive(indexName: String, searchSourceBuilder:SearchSourceBuilder): Flux<ESDocument> {
    return clientReader.search(SearchRequest().indices(indexName).source(searchSourceBuilder))
        .delaySubscription(Duration.ofMillis(10))
        .concatMap { searchHit ->
            val esDocument = ESDocument(searchHit.index, searchHit.type, searchHit.id, searchHit.sourceAsMap, searchHit.version)
            val lastHit = searchHit.sortValues[0]

            if (lastHit != null) {
                Flux.just(esDocument)
            } else {
                searchSourceBuilder.searchAfter(searchHit.sortValues)
                Flux.just(esDocument).concatWith(searchRecursive(indexName, searchSourceBuilder))
            }
        }
 }
}
```